# how to make session update the value in php?

Tags: php, session

I can't update my session value

this is the code

```
<CENTER>
<?PHP
    session_start();


$_SESSION['value'] = 15;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $plus = 10;
    $_SESSION['value'] = ($_SESSION['value']  + $plus);
    }

echo "<FORM METHOD=post ACTION=\"?page=try&". time(). "\" NAME=try>\n"; 
echo "<br>";
echo "Your value :" .$_SESSION['value'];
echo "<INPUT TYPE=submit NAME=submit VALUE=\"Submit\"></FORM>";
?>
</CENTER>
```

the problem is everytime I click that button, it always give me the same result.

that `$_SESSION['value']` is always 15 and it never changes

so how to update the session value ? so I will get `$_SESSION['value']` become 35 (the past result is 25 ) when I click the button again

thanks

Comment: Please don't use the `<center>` tag. It hurts my eyes.

Comment: Also, unless you are using output buffering, then the `session_start()` _should_ be giving you a warning, seeing as how you have output before it.  Please read more into PHP sessions!

Comment: `$_SESSION['value']` should become `25` (`15+10=25`) after you click the submit button and not `35` as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Lion I already said that "become 35 after I click that button again" what i mean is it will give me 35 after i have 25

Comment: I was confusing to read this prior to your edit "*$_SESSION['value'] is always 25*". Now, you have changed `25` to `15`. It's quite obvious. You're assigning `$_SESSION['value'] = 15;` everytime the page is loaded. How likely is it to get `35`?

Comment: I change `25` to `15` ? what I mean `become 35` is everytime I click that button it is always give me the result 25 so how to make the value become is 35 after the result is 25 when I click again

Comment: As the answer below says put that assignment within an `if` condition like this `if(!isset($_SESSION['value']))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you explicitly set the session value to 15, and then add 10 to it. It should never reach 35. try removing the assignment to 15 (or better yet, adding an `if(!isset($_SESSION['value']))` check before it) and then try again

You should also take John Conde's advice and make sure that **you start the PHP session before sending any output**.  Please read [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: I already try @JohnConde code but its still give the result 25

Comment: @devzlyx the issue you are asking about has nothing to do with JohnConde's suggestion.  John Conde's suggestion is an answer to an issue you haven't even asked about, but still exists in your code.  You do not send output before you call `session_start()`, period. `session_start()` modifies the headers being sent to the client which will issue a warning when output has already started. My answer, on the other hand, will give you the output you are expecting.

Comment: oops sorry I'm bit confused when I read it, but now its already work thanks

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` has to be before any output is sent to the browser (when using cookie based sessions).

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<CENTER>
<?php
$_SESSION['value'] = 15;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $plus = 10;
        $_SESSION['value'] = ($_SESSION['value']  + $plus);
    }

echo $_SESSION['value'];
echo '<form method="post" action="try1.php" name="try">' . "\n";
echo '<br>';
echo 'Your value :' . $_SESSION['value'];
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>';
?>
</CENTER>
```